# Links and Images Embedding Regexes

Tags: php, regex, parsing, pcre

SO Community!

I am new to regular expressions and I have a trouble with them.
I have a chat script with simple parser of user data.
There is an ability to embed an image with BBCode tag, like this: `[img]http://example.com/image.png[/img]`.
I also want to do automatic link transformation to valid hyperlinks.
I have two processing REGEXes, and I don't know how to solve the conflict between them.

To process `[img]` tag I use this and it executes first:

```
$line = preg_replace('/\[img\](https?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9%\-_?&=:+.\/]+)\[\/img\]/iU', '<a href="$1" target="_blank"><img class="incl_img" src="$1"></a>', $line, 5);
```

Then to process links I use this:

```
$line = preg_replace('#(https?:\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)\/?[a-zA-Z0-9?&=.:\#\/\-_~%+]*)#e', '\'[<a href="$1" title="$1" target="_blank">$2</a>]\'',$line);
```

And when user posts an image the link processing regex breaks `<img>` tag by inserting its `<a href=...` instead of link. How to avoid it without using special `[url]` tag or something else? How to separate `[img]` tags from simple links? Any corrections of regexes and/or algorithms are welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. The solution is to correct the second regex (URL parser) and add some conditions. New regex will look like this:

```
#(?<!src="|href=")(https?:\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+)\/?[a-zA-Z0-9?&=.:\#\/\-_~%+]*)#e'
```

And the whole code became this:

```
$line = preg_replace('#(?<!src="|href=")(https?:\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+)\/?[a-zA-Z0-9?&=.:\#\/\-_~%+]*)#e', '\'[<a href="$1" title="$1" target="_blank">$2</a>]\'',$line);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this little helper function:

```
function parseCode($txt)
{
   // these functions will clean the code first
   $ret = strip_tags($txt);

   // code replacements
   $ret = preg_replace('#\[link\=(.+)\](.+)\[\/link\]#iUs', '<a href="$1">$2</a>', $ret);
   $ret = preg_replace('#\[img\](.+)\[\/img\]#iUs', '<img src="$1" alt="Image" />', $ret);

   // return parsed string
   return $ret;
}
```

usage:

```
echo parseCode('[link=https://www.google.com]Click here to go to google[/link]');
echo "<br />";
echo parseCode('[img]https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo11w.png[/img]');
```

Comment: Thank you for response, but I said that I don't want to use any BBCode tags to process links. Isn't it possible to make them highlighted automatically and ignore them when they are used in `[img]` tag?